# What's the difference between VirtualTimeScheduler and TestScheduler?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

I see in Rxjs tests sometimes `TestScheduler` and sometimes `VirtualTimeScheduler`. 
Could you explain what's the difference and where should I use what?

```js
declare const rxTestScheduler: TestScheduler;
const scheduler = new VirtualTimeScheduler();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VirtualTimeScheduler` is a scheduler that doesn't use real time and lets you use Observables and operators that need to work with real time by creating an ordered list of events. Then you can flush all queued events and they will be processed one after another.

For example when you use `delay`:

```
import { of, VirtualTimeScheduler } from 'rxjs'; 
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

const scheduler = new VirtualTimeScheduler();

of(1).pipe(
  delay(100000, scheduler),
).subscribe(console.log);

scheduler.flush();
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-zcmxg1

Notice, that even when using `100000` you don't really wait 100s and the result is immediate. You'll probably never need to use `VirtualTimeScheduler` itself (or at least I've never seen any use-case for it).

Then `TestScheduler` only extends `VirtualTimeScheduler` with some additional methods for working with marble diagrams.